# sed not matching pattern in presence of unidentified characters

Tags: sed, special-characters

I am trying to weed out all content between `//` and end-of-line from a file on any line that matches.

So I am doing:

`sed -i -e 's://.*$::g' file`

And it works almost perfectly. Except for this pesky line with these special characters which is left untouched.

`// Date � � � Owner � � � � � � �Short description`

I don't know what those characters are and I don't really care.
Why is `.*` not matching those characters?

Comment: It works fine for me (GNU sed 4.7).  What OS and sed are you using?  Does your sed support unicode?  Is there a mismatch between your OS's default encoding and the encoding in the file?

Comment: @John1024 `sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1` .. How do I know if my sed supports unicode? My OS default encoding is utf-8. And file encoding is iso-8859-1. Hmm. Any tips on what to do?

Comment: Having inconsistent encodings can only lead to trouble.  Convert the input file to your system's default, UTF8.  There are several utilities that can do this.  One is `iconv`.  Try:  `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 file >newfile` and then use `newfile`.

Comment: If these special characters are the result of an ill-formed multibyte encoding, they may break the line parser. You can try to work around that using the C locale (single-byte) for this call, like `LC_CTYPE=C sed -i -e 's://.*::' file` with bash.

Comment: Thanks @John1024. Your `iconv` command works perfect! Can you please make it the answer? 

@luciole75w Setting LC_CTYPE=C did not make a difference (for that command or exporting it in the shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having inconsistent encodings between a file (iso-8859-1 in this case) and the operating system (UTF-8 in this case) can easily lead to trouble.

Convert the input file to your system's default, UTF8. There are several utilities that can do this. One is iconv. Try:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 file >newfile
```

and then use `newfile`.

#### Aside

Another subtle issue is line-endings.  If the source file is `iso-8859-1`, was it ever edited on a Windows machine?  If so, it might have DOS/Windows line-endings which cause a variety of non-obvious issues when used with Unix tools.  Use `dos2unix` or a similar utility to convert the line-endings.

Comment: If it's only one line it might make sense to just delete it with `sed 's://.*$::g; /\/\/\ Date/d' file` and not worry about line endings, but obviously there are caveats to that as well.